# overload new and delete causes valgrind errors

Tags: c++, valgrind

Valgrind is complaining about this code, I really don't understand why?

```
==9144==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: attempting double-free on 0x60200000eff0 in thread T0:
```

Full [logs](https://ideone.com/NKv7zY)

I am using a custom allocater for my code but below is the shorter version of it which is showing the same symptom. If I am running on a embedded system then I don't need to deallocate memory but I always want to make sure that I am not leaking any memory when running on x86 based system and I am using valgrind to verify that.

```
/*
g++ test.cpp -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer
./a.out
*/

 #include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                                                        

 class TestMemoryPool{                                                                                                                                                                                      
 };                                                                                                                                                                                                         

 void* operator new(size_t n, TestMemoryPool* pool)                                                                                                                                                         
 {                
 #ifdef CUSTOM_ALLOCATER
     //snip
 #else                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
     void *tmp = ::operator new(n);                                                                                                                                                                         
     return tmp;  
 #endif                                                                                                                                                                                          
 }                                                                                                                                                                                                          

 void* operator new[](size_t n , TestMemoryPool* pool)                                                                                                                                                      
 {         
 #ifdef CUSTOM_ALLOCATER
     //snip
 #else                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
     void *tmp = ::operator new(n);                                                                                                                                                                         
     return tmp;   
 #endif                                                                                                                                                                                         
 }                                                                                                                                                                                                          

 void operator delete(void* ptr, TestMemoryPool* pool)                                                                                                                                                      
 {         
 #ifdef CUSTOM_ALLOCATER
     //snip
 #else                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
     ::operator delete(ptr);       
 #endif                                                                                                                                                                         
 }                                                                                                                                                                                                          

 void operator delete[](void* ptr , TestMemoryPool* pool)                                                                                                                                                   
 {          
 #ifdef CUSTOM_ALLOCATER
     //snip
 #else                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
     ::operator delete(ptr);   
 #endif                                                                                                                                                                             
 }                                                                                                                                                                                                          

 int main()                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 {                                                                                                                                                                                                          
     TestMemoryPool *pool;                                                                                                                                                                                  
     float *signalGen = new (pool) float[100];                                                                                                                                                              
     TestMemoryPool *p = new (pool) TestMemoryPool();                                                                                                                                                       
     operator delete[](signalGen, pool);                                                                                                                                                                    
     operator delete(p, pool);                                                                                                                                                                              
     delete p;                                                                                                                                                                                              
 }
```

Comment: `operator delete(p, pool);` directly followed by `delete p;`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: sorry, removed it.

Comment: First of all `pool` is used unintialized, even though it is not really accesses it is still an UB.

Comment: @user7860670: it is not used so it does't matter

Comment: It is used in the next line: `new (pool) float[100]; `. Copying uninitialized pointer is UB.

Comment: @user7860670: it is passed to overloaded function where it is not used, no?

Comment: just passing it to function uses it to copy initialize function parameter

Comment: Any use of indeterminate values, even passing to function where it's not used, still counts as a use of the value (since it's used in the argument passing). And using an indeterminate value in any way leads to UB. Please enable verbose warnings when building and treat them as errors. And if you don't use it then just initialize it to be a null pointer.

Comment: With this extra `delete p;` Removed, do you still get the Valgrind error?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Now I am not getting it, can you put that as answer so that I can resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the double-free error because you are deleting the pointer `p` twice:

```
operator delete(p, pool);
delete p;
```